# Where can I find a list the google closure editor plugins?

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library

I find the google closure documentation difficult to navigate and I can't seem to find a list of the plugins I need to reference to use with my editor field?

Could anyone point me to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/namespace_goog_editor_plugins.html